# Accessing current_user in one class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, parameters, model

I am using the gem csv-importer, which gives me a class that I use to import csv data into my rails database

However, I need to know the current user when I am uploading a csv file, but Rails does not grant access to current_user in the class

I would like to pass custom parameters (such as current_user data) from my controller into the import_csv class when it is being called, how do I do that?

the import_csv class is called using

```
import = ImportUserCSV.new(file: file)
import.run!
```

I tried a solution in which I have current_user available for all classes, this worked for localhost but broke on Heroku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
import = ImportUserCSV.new(file: my_file) do
  after_build do |user|
     # here you have access to current_user 
  end
end
```

Comment: This seems to work, but it triggers major run time issues for some reason. Site freezes

Comment: it conflicts withe after_build already in the csv-import class it looks like, can I change one of them to after_save?

Comment: `after_build` is called when an object is build (before save) and `after_save` is called after `save` method is called. you can read more [here](https://github.com/pcreux/csv-importer#after_build-and-after_save-callbacks)